# Joining Meshes to Curves

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

HELP! I need to know how to join Bezier curves to a mesh. I am trying to make a car with curved rims and the easiest way was to use a Bezier curve and then to bevel it but I need to join it all together in order to put it in my mod.[image: My car with curved rims]

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by converting the curves to meshes then joining all the meshes together. Beware that this is a destructive process and will prevent you from making any further edits to the Bezier profile.

To convert the curves to meshes, select each one, set the preferred resolutions from the *Object Data* (Curve) panel, these will affect how many polygons your mesh will be made of, then do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh from Curve*.

Under Blender 2.8+ this is now found under the 3D View header menu *Object > Convert > Mesh*.

Then, select all the meshes (possibly the car as the latest) and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them.

Please note that this only assigns all the vertices/edges/faces to a single mesh object, but doesn't make smooth intersections or such.

For those use a [boolean operation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63861/how-can-i-merge-these-two-spherical-objects-into-a-single-smooth-mesh) instead.

Comment: Would add that another way to fuse the meshes after conversion would be touse the boolean modifier if you want to get rid of intersecting geometry, and make them a single solid object. If the two parts has no intersections or if you dont care of intersectiong geometry, join is just fine.