# How to combine multiple hemispheres into a single smooth mesh properly?

Tags: mesh

I am making an object which is made by combining one big hemisphere and four small hemispheres. Here is what I've done:
[image]

As you can see, one of the small hemispheres merges well with the big hemispheres while one merges not too properly.
[image]

Here is the mesh:
[image]
[This is the post I followed to make the object.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63861/how-can-i-merge-these-two-spherical-objects-into-a-single-smooth-mesh)

I made three spheres (one large sphere and two small spheres) first, follow the instructions to combine them, cut the upper half of the object and apply a mirror modifier.

However, when I tried to use Damped Track modifier on the second small sphere, the modifier align them in a way which the first small sphere overlaps with the second one. I think this is because I set the Damped Track Contraints to be Z for both small sphere, but if I set it to be other directions, the mesh will become what I've made above, which the second sphere cannot merge well with the big sphere.

Please help and I appreciate all the kindly assistance.

Comment: did you use a boolean operation?

Comment: Yes, I used the boolean modifier to combine the spheres together.

Comment: You will probably want to go with topology similar to this: https://imgur.com/kDLn4Uy It's 100% quad topology. I have used several different methods to achieve this and making an answer from it would be huge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any guideline or tutorial I can go through to learn about the technique you're talking about?

Comment: I can make an overview of this particular creation and point you in the right direction. There are tutorials on every technique I've used there.

Comment: also in the picture above, it looks like the small sphere centers are not aligned exactly with the center of the big one... or the section in half was not done exactly at the center. That leaves a lot of small faces  to fill up. Making sure the objects are well positioned (snapping or manually entering coordinates) before boolean and bisecting would probably help.

Comment: @LukeD Yes, please help. I totally have no idea to fix the problem since I am still a beginner.

Comment: @Bruno I think they should be aligned well, but I did add some loops to sharpen the edge, which looks like they are not aligned well.

Comment: Is it possible for me to redraw all the edges where the merging messed up?

Answer (score 1):

did you try "Auto Smooth" feature:

I tried to reproduce your problem, here is the result without Auto-smooth:
[image]

And with it, set with a 30deg angle:

[image]

I tried to play around with individual Edge sharpening without success.

Comment: I tried but the problem still exists. However, the edges did look like smoother with auto-smooth.