# How to fix warped faces when using boolean modifier on curved objects?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I'm trying to merge 2 like obects (1 rotated at a degree to make an "X" shape) and I can't seem to do it without warping the faces at the seams where the objects merge. Is there a way to fix this? Or do I have to manually fix the points? I've tried using "smooth vertices" but that just made it worse. I even tried this tutorial ( [How can I merge these two spherical objects into a single smooth mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63861/how-can-i-merge-these-two-spherical-objects-into-a-single-smooth-mesh) ) but no luck.

[image: Seems show diamond shapes]

[image: The two objects]

[image: closeup after using "smooth vertices"]

[image: This is how I want it to resolve the merged vertices (visual reference; this is still 2 objects not merged)]

Comment: hello, I guess you need to correct by hand, but maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots here [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=q2ORp5eb" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/q2ORp5eb/) 
EDIT: the reason I want to merge these with perfect seams is because I need to use a glass texture and render in high resolutions; where a warped seam will surely show up and ruin the flow.

Comment: Avoid so many subdivisions until you have the overall shapes worked out. Use subsurf modifiers instead. It is  a lot easier to combine different meshes that way.

Answer (score 1):

First, unless you have good reason to keep it high-poly, I would simplify with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*:

[image]

Then boolean it, give it some corrections like dissolve or merge some vertices, when you're good on a side or on the front, use *Symmetrize*:

[image]

Create a bevel on the joint:

[image]

It looks good. If you want a higher poly, subdivide.

[image]